# Reformat JSON with Groovy. Remove child node whilst keeping the contents

Tags: json, groovy

I am trying to reformat JSON to remove child nodes from some JSON objects whilst keeping whats inside the child node. (unsure how to explain, like removing the title node). In this example i am trying to have a `JSONarray` of groups without the `UserGroup` child node (whilst keeping each `UserGroups` content intact). Example JSON

```json
{
  "groups":[
    {
      "UserGroup":{
        "integrationKey":"0000073807",
        "uid":"0000073807"
      },
      "UserGroup":{
        "integrationKey":"0000073810",
        "uid":"0000073810"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What I'd like after processing

```json
{
  "groups":[
    {
      "integrationKey":"0000073807",
      "uid":"0000073807"
    },
    {
      "integrationKey":"0000073810",
      "uid":"0000073810"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the JSON with no duplicated keys, which formats the data, removing child keys may look like

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

def inputJson = '''
{
    "groups": [{
        "UserGroup1": {
                "integrationKey": "0000073807",
                "uid": "0000073807"
            },
        "UserGroup2": {
            "integrationKey": "0000073810",
            "uid": "0000073810"
        }
        }
    ]
}
'''
Map parsed = new JsonSlurper().parseText(inputJson) as Map
parsed.each {
    parsed[it.key] = it.value*.values().flatten()
}
println JsonOutput.toJson(parsed)
```

This code will print

```json
{"groups":[{"integrationKey":"0000073807","uid":"0000073807"},{"integrationKey":"0000073810","uid":"0000073810"}]}
```

**Handle duplicated key**

But your provided input example contains 2 items with `UserGroup` name. It's not common for JSON and most parsers just take the last mentioned value for the key. To handle this you can use below dependency

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
</dependency>
```

And modify the above script to

```
import net.sf.json.JSONObject

// ...
ipuptJson = JSONObject.fromObject(inputJson).toString()
Map parsed = new JsonSlurper().parseText(inputJson) as Map
parsed.each {
    parsed[it.key] = it.value*.values().flatten()
}
println JsonOutput.toJson(parsed)
```

Comment: Hi, great answer, and helped my understanding. Unfortunately The systems we use wont allow that import and now looking at renaming the node names to be unique and applying your first solution.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from terminology, you are not really modifiyng the json itself. In fact you can modify the in-memory representation of it exposed as a mixture of Lists, Maps and primitive object types.

The simplest way to do what you want would be:

```
import groovy.json.*

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText '''
{
    "groups": [{
        "UserGroup1": {
                "integrationKey": "0000073807",
                "uid": "0000073807"
            },
        "UserGroup2": {
            "integrationKey": "0000073810",
            "uid": "0000073810"
        }
        }
    ]
}
'''

def modified = [ groups:json.groups*.values().flatten() ]

println JsonOutput.prettyPrint( JsonOutput.toJson( modified ) )
```

prints:

```
{
    "groups": [
        {
            "integrationKey": "0000073807",
            "uid": "0000073807"
        },
        {
            "integrationKey": "0000073810",
            "uid": "0000073810"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: As I'm trying to modify the memory of two key duplicates, this answer doesn't work. Thanks for your response though, helps me understand better.